# Call function from Main()

Tags: c#, static-methods, instance-methods

I am new to C# and I'm having a little problem with calling a function from the `Main()` method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("test2");
        mi.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public void test2()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Test2");
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error in `test();`:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field.

I don't quite understand these modifiers yet so what am I doing wrong?

What I really want to do is have the `test()` code inside `Main()` but it gives me an error when I do that.

Comment: As the error message tells you, you need an object reference to call a non-static member.  So create an object reference.

Comment: From a method? How is that possible to make an object from a method? or do you mean I have to put the test() in a new class?

Comment: You need an instance of the type the method is defined in, to call an instance method of that type.  The same is just as true in obj-c, I'm sure.

Comment: Why downvote? I didnt do anything wrong!

Comment: You didn't even do basic research before asking the question.  Doing something as simple as performing a web search on the error message leads to plenty of information on exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I tried this.test() but still error, thats the objc syntax

Comment: In static context you don't have `this` or any other 'attributes' belonging to an instance context.

Comment: @Servy I thought the error was too wide so I didnt really know what to search for.

Comment: @Arbitur So you didn't even *bother* to look for an answer because you assumed that you wouldn't find one?  Don't do that.  Look for an answer.  If, after spending a fair bit of time both trying to solve the problem and looking for a solution, *then* consider posting a question on Stack Overflow.  If you are unwilling to do something as simple as perform a web search on your issue, you should expect downvotes.  That someone would upvote a question for which the author is unwilling to even perform a single web search is very disappointing for me.

Comment: Why you just don't call `Console.WriteLine("Test2");` from the `Main` method? All of this just to show a simple message. If you want to learn about reflection, try not to use a static context to do this.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira Please dont ask why, this is just for testing, not what I want in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put all logic to another class

```
 class Class1
    {
        public void test()
        {
            MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("test2");
            mi.Invoke(this, null);
        }
        public void test2()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Test2");
        }
    }
```

and

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var class1 = new Class1();
            class1.test();
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you still want to have `test()` as an instance method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.test();
    }

    void Test()
    {
        // I'm NOT static
        // I belong to an instance of the 'Program' class
        // You must have an instance to call me
    }
}
```

or rather make it static:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        // I'm static
        // You can call me from another static method
    }
}
```

---

To get the info of a static method:

```
typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test", BindingFlags.Static);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method must be static in order to call it.

Comment: Thats the problem I cant use the MethodInfo in a static method.

Comment: The method is not static.

Comment: @Arbitur The type of a static method is always known at compile time; there is no need to get it dynamically.